# magento checkout button url

Tags: checkout, magento-1.7

i'm not good at programming.. In my shopping cart when users click on the "checkout" button it directly goes to mydomain.com/checkout/onepagecheckout.

when i turn off the onepagecheckout via admin panel, my "checkout" button goes to mydomain.com/checkout/cart

But i want to use the mydomain.com/checkout/cart with onepagecheckout.

All i want is, when users click on the "checkout" button it should go to mydomain.com/checkout/cart and then from there it should go to the "onepagecheckout".

help me please!

thanks alot.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for checkout url

```
Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');
```

Comment: Hi thanks alot for reading my question. As i said before i'm not good with magento can you please expand your answer...

kindly visit this page also [link]http://store.redstage.com/checkout/cart/[link] 

there "proceed to checkout" goes to the onepagecheckout page, but in my shop it only goes to the multiple address checkout.

if i enable the onepagecheckout it directly goes to the onepagecheckout, without going to the checkout/cart page... it would be great if you expand your answer,

thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

For you

```
Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepagecheckout');
```

But default for lint Proceed to Checkout has used:

```
Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
```